# Visual C++: What is a dynamically linked .lib file?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, libraries

I noticed the following about a library I use:

- Library is compiled to **.lib** file.
- My code needs to be compiled as **Multi-threaded (Debug) DLL** to link to this library.

I open the **.sln** (solution) file of the library (it is open source) and see the following in its **Project properties**:

1. **Runtime Library** option is set to **Multi-threaded (Debug) DLL**.
2. **Configuration Type** is set to **Static Library (.lib)**

My confusion is:

1. Isn't there a conflict in the library options above? (Static Library says one option, DLL says another)
2. What kind of an animal is a **.lib** that is **dynamically linked**? How is it different from a **DLL**?

Note that I am aware of the difference between static libraries and dynamic libraries in the Linux world.

Answer (score 3):

The "RunTime Library" option isn't about YOUR library. It tells the compiler that you'll import your functions from `MSVCRTxx.DLL` at runtime.

The "configuration Type" option does refer to your library, and therefore is independent of the "RunTime Library" option.

Answer (score 2):

A Windows DLL can be dynamically loaded with the [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx) (or LoadLibraryEx) API, but then you have to find and bind each exported function to a function pointer using [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(VS.85).aspx) or GetProcAddressEx. You'd better get the function signatures right, or Bad Things Will Happen, as usual.

A LIB file allows Windows to do all that for you when your EXE is started (including finding which DLL to use, and recursively loading dependent DLL's), linking the dynamic library statically at run time, while avoiding bloating your EXE file with the executable code, and allowing several processes to share the same DLL image in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the config mismatch, but a .LIB file when created with a .DLL library is an "export library" - it doesn't contain any code, but just the names of the callable functions and objects in the DLL. The linker uses this to satisfy references at link time which are finally resolved by dynamic loading at run-time.

Comment: I am not able to see any DLL file of this library anywhere. Yet, my code can link to the .lib and execute! Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ashwin Sounds like you have a static library then. The best bet is to examine your executable with Dependency Walker a free tool from avaialble at http://dependencywalker.com/ and see what it is actually depending on.

Comment: Neil Butterworth: If you are curious, the library is wxWidgets. Checked my .exe with Dependency Walker & I cannot find any wx*.dll. My .exe is built as Multi-threaded DLL & links to wx*.lib. How is this possible? :-)

Comment: @Ashwin I know nothing about wxWidgets, so I can't help there I'm afraid.